# Cannot get width of Element created in same function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create multiply divs programmatically and set one divs width to the others width, kind of like this:

```js
var container1 = document.createElement("div");
container1.style.width = "400px";
container1.appendChild(document.createElement("h1"));
container1.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Hello there!";
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(container1);

var container2 = document.createElement("div");
container2.style.width = container1.offsetWidth;
container2.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
container2.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML = "My width is " + container2.offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(container2);
```

```css
#frame div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Why can't I get the offsetWidth of the Element? Is there something I may understand wrong about how elements are created, inserted and calculated by the browser?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `clientWidth`

Comment: I don't know how i evenutaly lost the "px" in the progress of finding this out. I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `"px"` affter the width:

You can only get `container2` width after appending to the `html`

```js
var container1 = document.createElement("div");
container1.style.width = "400px";
container1.appendChild(document.createElement("h1"));
container1.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Hello there!";
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(container1);

var container2 = document.createElement("div");
container2.style.width = container1.offsetWidth + "px";
//                                        here ^^^^^^^ 
container2.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
container2.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML = "My width is " + container2.offsetWidth; //Wont be able to get width here as you did not add to HTML yet!
document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(container2);
container2.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML = "My width is " + container2.offsetWidth;
```

```css
#frame div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! I changed so many things, I eventually forgot to add the "px". Sorry for not seeing it :)

Comment: @Simon No problem... Happy coding.. Don't forget to accept answer :)

Comment: @HarikrishnanN He forgot :D

Comment: Sorry was out for lunch! :D